# Trying to get a ListBox of CheckBoxes to group and have a 'Select All' button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I am trying to create a search menu in my WPF application. So, naturally I have a bunch of different search criteria in 4 different ListBoxes. I am having a hard time with configuring a 'Select All' Checkbox to uncheck all of the other CheckBoxes in the ListBox.

Here is a sample of one of the ListBoxes:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="RegionSelection" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource LabelTextblockStyle}"
       VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="4,4,4,4">Regions:</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

            <ListBox  Margin="4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RegionTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource NoHighlightList}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=RegionDesc}" Command="{Binding Path=UncheckAllCommand}" Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
     private List<SearchRegion> _regionTypes;
    public List<SearchRegion> RegionTypes
    {
        get { return _regionTypes; }
        set
        {
            _regionTypes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    RegionTypes = new List<SearchRegion>
        {   new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "All Regions"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 4", Region="4"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 1", Region="1"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 5", Region="5"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 2", Region="2"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 6", Region="6"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 3", Region="3"}
        };
```

And the Command:

```
    UncheckAllCommand = new RelayCommand(UncheckAll);
    public ICommand UncheckAllCommand {get; private set;}
     private void UncheckAll()
    {
        if(RegionTypes.Any((x) => x.RegionDesc.ToUpper().Equals("ALL REGIONS") && x.IsChecked))
        {
            RegionTypes.ForEach((x) => x.IsChecked = x.RegionDesc.ToUpper() != "ALL REGIONS" ? false : true);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, its just not unchecking the rest of the ListBox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to add the Class that holds the properties of the SearchRegion. Here it is:

```
    public class SearchRegion : BaseModel
{

        public SearchRegion() { }


        public string RegionDesc { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }

    bool _isChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: My goal is to have all of the other checkboxes get unchecked, leaving only the 'All Regions' box checked. Adding the RaisePropertyChanged ("RegionTypes") did not change the behavior of the search menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answering my own question, this is how I solved it. Keep in mind there are tons of ways to do what I wanted, but this is how is stumbled through it.

In my view I didn't need the Command, because I created a templist that was manipulated then notifies the view. So here is the view:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="RegionSelection" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource LabelTextblockStyle}"
       VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="4,4,4,4">Regions:</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
           <ListBox  Margin="4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RegionTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource NoHighlightList}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=RegionDesc}"  Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

In the ViewModel, I had to swap the 'List' for  'ObservableCollection' so here is where I have that:

```
         private ObservableCollection<SearchRegion> _regionTypes;
    public ObservableCollection<SearchRegion> RegionTypes
    {
        get { return _regionTypes; }
        set
        {
            _regionTypes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    RegionTypes = new ObservableCollection<SearchRegion>
        {   new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "All Regions"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 4", Region="4"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 1", Region="1"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 5", Region="5"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 2", Region="2"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 6", Region="6"},
            new SearchRegion {RegionDesc = "Region 3", Region="3"}
        };
```

Then I created some logic to act as an event, that allowed me to have the logic run only when the 'All Regions' checkbox was selected.

```
     foreach(var region in RegionTypes.Where((x) => x.RegionDesc.ToUpper().Equals("ALL REGIONS")))
            region.PropertyChanged += UncheckAll;
```

Here is the logic that changes the state of the checkboxes that aren't 'All Regions'

```
     if (RegionTypes.Any((x) => x.RegionDesc.ToUpper().Equals("ALL REGIONS") && x.IsChecked))
        {
            foreach (var region in tempRegions.Where((x) => !x.RegionDesc.ToUpper().Equals("ALL REGIONS")))
                region.IsChecked = true;
    }

        RegionTypes = new ObservableCollection<SearchRegion>();
        RegionTypes = tempRegions;
```

So that's it. I created the templist, from the Region types then set the region types to the values in the templist after the logic completes. 
Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I found 2 issues.

1) Your model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class SearchRegion : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SearchRegion() { }

    public string RegionDesc { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }

    bool _isChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

2) If command `UncheckAllCommand` is in ViewModel, your binding should looks like this:

```
...
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=RegionDesc}" 
                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UncheckAllCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBox}}" 
                      Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
...
```

If you write something like this:

```
...
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=RegionDesc}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=UncheckAllCommand}" 
            Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
...
```

you expect that `UncheckAllCommand` is declared in model class (in your case it is `SearchRegion` class).